# Proving an inequality using am-gm inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove that if $x\neq y\neq z$, $x,y,z\gt0$
$$\frac{x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2y^2}{x+y+z}\geqslant xyz$$

I tried using
$$x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2\gt 3\root3\of{x^4y^4z^4}$$
$$x+y+z\gt 3\root3\of{xyz}$$
But I can't divide both LHS and RHS

Then I tried to prove that
$x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2\geqslant xyz(x+y+z)$, so I used
$$x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2\gt 3\root3\of{x^4y^4z^4}$$
$$xyz(x+y+z) \gt 3\root3\of{x^4y^4z^4}$$

Then I got stuck as I can't subtract the two inequalities either (only addition or multiplication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the known inequality $$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ca$$ we get
$$(xy)^2+(yz)^2+(zx)^2\geq xyyz+xyxz+yzzx=xy^2z+x^2yz+xyz^2=(xyz)(x+y+z)$$
The first inequality is equivalent to $$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\geq 0$$

Comment: Is the equal sign correct? Or is it only greater than? Because x, y and z are not equal.

Comment: We do not need the condition $$x\neq y\neq z$$,  but if we assume $$x\neq y\neq z$$ then the equal sign does not hold. But we can say that $$\geq $$ mean greater or equal.

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM
$$\sum_{cyc }x^2y^2=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x^2y^2+x^2z^2)\geq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}2\sqrt{x^2y^2\cdot x^2z^2}=\sum_{cyc}x^2yz=xyz(x+y+z).$$